# ControlTemplate Trigger don't work in designer (runtime ok)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, dependency-properties, wpf-style

I have a custom Control derived from Window:

```
class LVSDialog : Window
```

with DependencyProperty `ShowCloseButton`

and a Style with ControlTemplate and Trigger:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type loc:LVSDialog}" x:Key="LVSDialogStyle">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        ...
        <Button x:Name="closeButton" />
        ...
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="loc:LVSDialog.ShowCloseButton" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="closeButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>            
    </Setter>
```

Everything works fine in the runtime, but in Designer it doesn't take sence if I change this Property - Button is visible all the time:

```
<loc:LVSDialog ...
    ShowCloseButton="False" Style="{StaticResource LVSDialogStyle}">
```

I have searched for a solution in google and here - all questions are about runtime functionality, designer problems are either unanswered or not working suggestions.

Is it possible at all use full functions in design time?

P.S. My VisualStudio is 2012. Framework 4.0

Comment: Is there a special reason you're using a Trigger for that and not simply a `TemplateBinding`?

Comment: @lokusking you mean `<Button ...  Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShowCloseButton, Converter={StaticResource TrueVisible}}" />`? This also works in runtime, but not in designer :(

Comment: The best advice you can get is, don't trust the designer, and avoid using it at all costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the base class to Control instead of Window it will work:

```
  public class LVSDialog : Control
  {


    public bool ShowCloseButton
    {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowCloseButtonProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ShowCloseButtonProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowCloseButton.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCloseButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCloseButton", typeof(bool), typeof(LVSDialog), new PropertyMetadata(true));


  }
```

> From Topicstarter:

I have changed to Control, added internal window, set it content to my control and added Show() and ShowDialog() methods:

```
private Window parentWindow;
...
public void Show()
{
    if (parentWindow == null)
    {
        parentWindow = new Window {Content = this, WindowStyle = ...};
    }
    parentWindow.Show();
}
```

Everything works fine, designer shows all properties "live".

Comment: How should I then using it? As content for empty window? What about styling? The reason I need custom window - is that i want to have it draggable and styled. How can I reach it best?

Comment: Ok, this works. Thank you.
I added internal window that contains my custom control and Show() and ShowDialog(), adjusted style and it works.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would not use a Window as an inline control (child of another control).
If you want to drag an visual element inline (not changing its position in the visual hierarchy) you can use RenderTransform og LayoutTransform.
If you want to drag it more freely (like floating toolbars or dockable windows) I would maybe put the (content)control in a Window when start dragging and leave it in the Window while dragging and floating.
But it's only thoughts - I have not used/tested it.

Comment: OK, i misunderstood you last comment.

Comment: no, window is not child of my control, instead - it contains my control! From external - I don't see this window, but my control behaves as window. My goal was to get custom window for dialogs and messages.